# How do I simply edit the subtitles of a MKV file while preserving the video, audio, and attachment streams?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitles, matroska, truetype-fonts

So when I look at the original video:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=index,codec_name,codec_type example.mkv
```

I see something like this:

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_type=video
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_type=audio
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=2
codec_name=ass
codec_type=subtitle
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=3
codec_name=ttf
codec_type=attachment
[/STREAM]
```

My process involves extracting the ass file via:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:s:0 subs.ass
```

I edit the subtitle file in `vim`. Then I try to add the subtitle file back into the mkv file with something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -f ass -i subs.ass  \
-map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy \
-c:s copy output.mkv
```

But when I probe the output.mkv, I only see

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_type=video
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_type=audio
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=2
codec_name=ass
codec_type=subtitle
[/STREAM]
```

As you can see, I lose the attachment stream, and the subtitles no longer play by default. So I came across other commands:

Make subtitle default:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mkv -f ass -i subs.ass -c copy -disposition:s:0 default out.mkv
```

Dump Font from the original:

```
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t "" -i original.mkv
```

Attach Font to edited video:

```
ffmpeg -i out.mkv -attach OpenSans-Semibold.ttf -metadata:s:3 mimetype=application/x-truetype-font final.mkv
```

But then somehow along those processes, the audio changes from `aac` to `vorbis`, and the video changes from `h264 (native)` to `h264 (libx264)`. How do I preserve the streams while making simple error changes to the subtitles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**#1** Extract subtitles

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -map 0:s:0 subs.ass
```

**#2** Mux edited subs

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i subs.ass  \
       -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -map 0:t -c copy -disposition:s:0 default output.mkv
```

Comment: Thank you! My old process took quite a while, but these two commands simply finish in seconds.